# Perl value is not sticking

Tags: perl

I know I am missing something simple here, but I can't figure it out and google is not working

I am trying to use the value for `$F` but it is not working. I will leave out some of the code. I get an error basically saying that `$f` requires a specific package name

```
sub captureFile()
{
    my $F = $File::Find::name;
    if ($F = ~/txt$/)
    {
      $F=~ s:(.*)(\/reports\/.*):$2:;
      loadEnvironmentProperties($F);
    }
 }


 sub loadEnvironmentProperties()
 {
    print $F;
 }
```

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always `use strict; use warnings;`!

You try to specify $F as an argument

```
loadEnvironmentProperties($F);
                          ^^
```

to a function you declared has no parameters

```
sub loadEnvironmentProperties()
                             ^^
```

and you never actually read the arguments in `loadEnvironmentProperties`. You want:

```
sub loadEnvironmentProperties {
   my ($F) = @_;
   print $F;
}
```

Comment: The op might be trying to close over `$F` in which case `my $F` should be outside `captureFile`. Then again, I prefer the style you propose most of the time. This is just for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

$F does not exist the second subroutine because you did not get it out the parameters array

```
sub loadEnvironmentProperties()
 {
    my $F = shift;
    print $F;
 }
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks Nate, that did it!